# Edit Flash Pro CS6 Layer

Tags: flash, flash-cs6

I am editing a flash file on my Adobe Flash Pro CS6.

I have three layers (see image on http://postimg.org/image/c4liq5viv/).

However, I wanted to *add more* files within the middle layer (as highlighted). How can I view the contents of its layers so that i can add more of its contents?

Answer (score 1):

You can make other layers unseen. Select other layers and press the 'eye' button. To make them seen again, just do the same again.

Comment: still i cant open the contents in the timeline. http://postimg.org/image/5b5hvkfcf/